# Match a pattern to select files out of a directory

Tags: r, directory

lets say i run the function `list.files()`

I will get a character vector looking like this:

```
 tst<-c("Test.Uncx4.1_2281.2_deBruijn.txt", "Test.Vax1_3499.1_deBruijn.txt", 
"Test.Vax2_3500.1_deBruijn.txt", "Test.Vsx1_1728.1_deBruijn.txt", 
"Train.Alx3_3418.2_deBruijn.txt", "Train.Alx4_1744.1_deBruijn.txt", 
"Train.Arx_1738.2_deBruijn.txt", "Train.Bapx1_2343.1_deBruijn.txt", 
"Train.Barhl1_2590.2_deBruijn.txt", "Train.Barhl2_3868.1_deBruijn.txt"
)
```

The problem I’m experiencing is when using the parameter `pattern` from `list.files()`
Like this: `list.files(dirs[1], pattern = "^[Train]",ignore.case=F)`

I still get all the files back while i`m expecting to get only the Train files.
like this:

```
c("Train.Alx3_3418.2_deBruijn.txt", "Train.Alx4_1744.1_deBruijn.txt", 
"Train.Arx_1738.2_deBruijn.txt", "Train.Bapx1_2343.1_deBruijn.txt", 
"Train.Barhl1_2590.2_deBruijn.txt", "Train.Barhl2_3868.1_deBruijn.txt")
```

How is this possible or what did i do wrong?

Comment: Remove the `[` and `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is :

```
list.files(dirs[1], pattern = "^Train",ignore.case=F)
```

With the pattern you provided, with the brackets, you were filtering for files whose names begin with T, r,  a, i or n.

Comment: Thanks! the help file showed the brackets but i`m now realizing that is only necessary when asking pattern for multiple patterns. (correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: No, it's not for multiple patterns. Brackets define a set of characters. So [ab] will match either the letter "a" or the letter "b", not the string "ab".

Comment: The brackets are for indexing a vector that probably has multiple directories.

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw I suggest reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html atleast once if you are going to use regex.. I promise it won't be waste of your time.